# char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)

Tags: c

I know how this function works. I know that `stdin` is often used as a `*stream`. It's rather question of interest, but is there any function else to be used for input instead of `stdin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you use `stdin` not as `*stream` but `stream`, as `stdin` is declared as

```
FILE *stdin;
```

Secondly, `stdin` is not a function, but an object - a pointer to an opaque structure describing an open *stream*; or as the name says, an open *file*. `stdin` is special in that in programs it is by default be connected to interactive input, i.e. whatever you type with your keyboard.

While `stdin` is an input stream readily provided to your program before `main` is executed, you can open many more streams with for example the `fopen` function:

```
FILE *a_file = fopen("myinput.txt", "r");
```

will open the file `myinput.txt` in the *current working directory* of the process for reading, and return a pointer to the structure describing the stream of bytes; calling `fgets(..., a_file);` will now read in consecutive lines of the said *file* starting from the beginning.

After reading the stream must be closed with `fclose(a_stream);`